# How does an isolated class (or group of isolated classes) fit into a Domain Model?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I am trying to refactor a large and complex application to use DDD principles as and when I get time.

I have a class, which is completely isolated from the domain (it is only used by an application service) but part of the ubiquitous language.  It looks like this (an old version of it):

```
public class CurrencyCalculator
{
    private readonly ICurrency currency;

    public CurrencyCalculator(ICurrency currency)
    {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, int>> CalculateDenominationsFor(int cost) 
    {
        var target = cost;
        foreach (var denomination in currency.AvailableDenominations.OrderByDescending(a => a))
        {
           var numberRequired = target / denomination;
           if (numberRequired > 0)
           {
               yield return new KeyValuePair<int, int>(denomination, numberRequired);
           }
           target = target - (numberRequired * denomination); 
        }
    } 
}
```

The class has a web front end and an application front end and is used by cashiers.

As it stands; this class exists in a class library project on its own (with currency class and interface).  **Is this an example of a domain service in DDD terminolgy**? (main question) Should it be in a class library named: Core? (the Core of the application).  If the answer is no, then what is this class - a utility?

The reason I ask is because I have improved my thinking of this domain recently.  However, I cannot see how this very simple class fits in to my domain model.

**Update**

Before I answer; I have two further thoughts:

1) My understanding of a Domain Service is that it is used when the logic is not a natural fit for an entity and the logic spans multiple bounded contexts/aggregate roots.  Is it normal to have a Domain Service, which does not reference any entities or value objects (like in this case)?

2) This specific application is CRUD based and this is the only Domain class.  Therefore I am thinking about moving it from the Core project (Domain Model) to the Application Service to simplify it.  I guess this would break DDD rules?

Comment: Seems to me an utility: 1. It's pure (has no side effects) 2. Has no domain logic 3. Either has external dependencies since ICurrency is part of the domain (the domain of the library) 4. Doesn't involves entities or value objects so it's fairly decoupled from the model.

Comment: @Laiv, thanks.  So where would I put this class.  What would the naming convention be for the class library? I realise this may sound a bit pedantic, however I am trying to follow convention.

Comment: What's wrong with the actual name? Would you say It reflects the purpose of the class? If not. What do you think would be more descriptive and acurated name? Regarding its place. Is the component reused in other modules or projects?

Comment: @Laiv, I thought the whole point of a Domain Service is that it is pure? Surely it does contain domain logic as it is telling the cashiers what denominations to use.

Comment: Before anything else, you should decide in what category is: *Application*, *Domain* or *Infrastructure*. If the domain model doesn't need the calculator and the calculator doesn't need the domain model, the likely category is *Application* (application service). But still, I get the feeling that application services interact with the top level elements of the domain model (for instance, repositories). In absence of this interaction and looking how the class has been implemented, I cannot but think in Application utils. I wonder what would @VoiceOfUnreason say regarding this question.

Comment: @Laiv, I see application services as there for orchestration.  Logic that applies to the domain (part of the ubiquitous language of the domain - the cashiers) should be in the domain model in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this an example of a domain service in DDD terminolgy?

I would say yes.

> Should it be in a class library named: Core? (the Core of the application).

I don't know what kind of library is Core. But it should be right along all other Entities or Services.

Thing that bothers me tho is name. `CurrencyCalculator` is too generic name. I would name it `CurrenciesDenomination`, so it is clear it is calculating denominations. And I would put it in `Currencies` "module" in the domain library. Most probably right next to `ICurrency` interface.

And it is true that the method could be turned into static method with `ICurrency` and `cost` parameters. And it could be turned into extension method. But it would still belong in domain in `Currencies` "module". It would NOT be an `utility`, whetever that means.

Comment: Why not services?

Comment: @Rekshino I don't undestand what you mean.

Comment: Just to be clear; you are suggesting an assembly called: com.MyApp.Core.CurrencyCalculator? Core refers to the Onion core.

Comment: @Euphoric Maybe it was misunderstanding on my side, I have understood from "But it should be right along all other Entities or Services", that class doesn't belong to services.

Comment: @Rekshino I still don't understand what you mean. It feels to me that your domain core is divided into Entities and Services. That is wrong. Domain library should be divided by domain concerns, not by technical concerns.

Comment: @Euphoric, can you answer the question in my comment above before I think about marking your answer? Thanks.

Comment: @w0051977 You mean the one about suggesting an assembly? I think I answered that in my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try to reprhrase the question.  What would you call the assembly containing the: Entities; Value Objects and Domain Services? Core? DomainModel? Logic?

Comment: @w0051977 DomainModel or just simply Domain seems fine to me. Or maybe call it what the bounding context name is. Or maybe Domain.{BoundedContextName}

Comment: Is there any references for this? I realise this is a bit pedantic, however I am trying to use the principle of least astonishment.

Comment: @w0051977 I don' think there are any. This is just my experience and opinions.

Comment: @Euphoric, do you still think it should be a Domain Service after reading Laivs' points (see Laivs' points listed in Rekshinos' answer)?  I believe the Domain Service is making a business decision, however on the other it is pure and has no side effects.

Comment: @w0051977 Purity and side effects have nothing to do whenever something belongs in domain or not. Things belong in domain if it is something domain expert would care about.

Comment: Thanks, +1 for "Purity and side effects have nothing to do whenever something belongs in domain or not".  I guess the domain experts (cashiers) care about it in this case do it should be in the domain model.  Do you agree with that in principle?

Comment: @w0051977 Yes, that is correct.

Comment: One more thing.  Q1) If I call the assembly: Company.System.BoundedContext, then I guess I could further split down the namespaces as: Company.System.BoundedContext.Aggregate?  Q2) In the case of my question case I may just call the assembly: Company.System as it is very simple.  Is this normal? Q3) Do you know of any open source projects that call the DomainModel: DomainModel or Domain.BoundedContext?

Comment: @Euphoric, I have added an update to my question.  Could you answer it before I mark an answer? +1.

Answer (score 0):

Laiv has pointed it out:

> 1. It's pure (has no side effects)
> 2. Has no domain logic
> 3. Either has external dependencies since `ICurrency` is part of the
>      domain (the domain of the library)
> 4. Doesn't involves entities or value objects so it's fairly decoupled
>      from the model.

However, I'm not sure whether it is right to see in #3 this isolated class as separate "domain".
If I look on all these points, then in terms DDD it belongs for me to **services**.

> When an operation does not conceptually belong to any object.
>   Following the natural contours of the problem, you can implement these
>   operations in services.

See: [DDD definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design).

Comment: I have also my doubts regarding services. I have been searching for differences between [domain and application services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839386/domain-services-vs-application-services) since DDD use to differentiate both. CurrencyCalculator is missing something, it doesn't operate with the domain. I would expect services (both domain and application) interacting with the domain

Comment: I would add one more point to my arguments. The method `CalculateDenominationsFor` could be static perfectly, turning the whole class into a common Utility class. Reading a little bit more about DDD services someone might get to the conclusion that it could be a *application service*. It makes sense too. I guess the answer lays on whether  the  calculator is reused often across boundaries, models and projects within the domain/project/company.

Comment: @Rekshino , I assume you are referring to domain services when you say: services?

Comment: @Laiv "it doesn't operate with the domain" But that is wrong. It is doing calculation with cost and curencies. That is a domain concern. It is something that domain expert would define.

Comment: @w0051977 Yes, I have meant domain services

Comment: @Euphoric I'm unsure about that. Reading the question I get to the conclusion that the class is not taking any business decision, it has no side-effects in the domain and there's no domain element to operate with. It's a mere converter. ICurrency (If I'm right) doesn't belong to the domain, it's one more resource for supporting the calculator. Seems to me too much isolation for to be part of the ubiquitous language. Despite the word currency and Denominations might appear marginally.

Comment: My understanding of Application Services is that they are somehow a facade for the Domain. As facade, at some point, they have to interoperate with domain elements. This doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @Laiv It's not just that it works with `Currency` (which, without a doubt, is a domain object). It's that it *does* enforce a rule. It may not seem explicit, but ask yourself this. Why does it `OrderByDescending`?

Answer (score 0):

Simple. This is a domain service. We know this because it knows about your domain. `Currency` is certainly a domain object. Furthermore, it encompasses a business rule. It enforces that in the event that a `Cashier` must give a `Customer` change, they do so with the least total number of legal tender. Should that rule change, say when a `Customer` pays with a 100 dollar bill and the change is greater than $50 `Cashiers` *must* use two 20 dollar bills instead of a 50, where else would that rule be enforced? Or what if, for some reason, a rule was made that a specific `Cashier` could only give 1 dollar bills as change? Now we would need more methods on this service to allow it's consumer to decide how to make change.

All of that said, I would suggest you think long and hard about what you name this service, because `CurrencyCalculator` certainly didn't end up exhibiting the behavior I thought it was going to exhibit when I first started reading your code. Take that with a grain of salt, but I would expect a service that calculates the change that a `Cashier` is supposed to give back to the `Customer` to somehow include those context clues in the name.