# Naming a Domain Model project

Tags: domain-driven-design, naming

This question follows on from my other question here: [How does an isolated class (or group of isolated classes) fit into a Domain Model?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/366333/how-does-an-isolated-class-or-group-of-isolated-classes-fit-into-a-domain-mode)

I have looked at a few domain models online:

- https://github.com/vkhorikov/DddInAction
- https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/tree/master/src/NHibernate.DomainModel
- https://github.com/zkavtaskin/Domain-Driven-Design-Example/tree/master/eCommerce/DomainModelLayer

They all have different naming conventions for the Domain Modelproject.  The first calls the project: Logic; the second calls it DomainModel and the third calls it: DomainModelLayer.

I have also seen questions on here, which recommend calling the Domain project: Core; Domain and Domain.BoundedContext etc e.g. this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865543/whats-a-recommended-solution-structure-for-a-somewhat-large-website-in-asp-net/6866482

A lot of the questions and Visual Studio solutions I have quoted date back to 2010/11.  Is there a recommended approach to this these days.  What should I expect when looking at the name of a domain model project?

Comment: Naming conventions are like opinions; everybody has one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What should I expect when looking at the name of a domain model project?

Most probably the naming should follow some kind of [**DSL**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) as proposed by [Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/books/dsl.html).

Without having any knowledge about the specifically addressed *problem domain*, it's hard to tell what you "can expect".

In the end it depends, how well the designers of some *Domain Model* grasped what is the most "natural naming" for their consumers and customers, and how the software developers can easily use these terms for their technical aspects.

That's the *"creative part"* (and art) software architects contribute, to glue the ***technical aspects*** and the ***problem domain specific terms*** together, such that it's easier to understand for the software developers and the customers at each other end.

---

The name of the *Domain Layer* of any system itself, is probably best described as *"Domain Model* or *"Domain Layer"*.

Another highly related concept is the [Domain Model](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html) (also from a [*Pattern Catalog*](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/index.html) proposed by M. Fowler).

---

<sub>I can't (counter) comment [@Robert Harway's comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/366386/naming-a-domain-model-project/366392#comment799081_366386) yet, though I don't believe that's entirely *"opinion based"*. There are methodologies and techniques you can apply, to get that right as mentioned above.</sub>

Comment: Thanks.  Do you use DomainModel or DomainLayer?